# Are these jQuery expressions equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, expression

I'm wondering if these two expressions are equivalent, because if they are, it would make this much easier.

`$('div', this).filter(':not(.trigger)')...`
`$('div:not([class*=trigger])', this)...`

(`this` providing a context under which to look for the specified `div`)

Comment: Incidentally the expressions themselves are perfectly normal CSS selectors, not jQuery-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not essentially the same. The second also filters out all div's which have a class which [**contains**](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeContains#attributevalue) "trigger" in the name, thus also e.g. "anothertrigger" and "triggerfoo".

You can also use

```
$('div:not(.trigger)', this)...
```

which is imho much clearer.

Comment: Maybe because I initially did give the clearer example. Sorry about that. Your answer was by the way initially also confusing because I didn't see that the OP edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Version 1 takes all divs without the class **trigger**.

Version 2 takes all the divs where the attribute class contains the text **trigger**.
This means a div with the class mytrigger will be a match.

[Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

**EDIT**

With your updated question this would be the equivalent to the first version.

```
$('div:not(.trigger)', this)
```

Comment: Alexsander: if you're looking for a statement equivalent to the first one, you can use `$('div:not(.trigger]))'`.